# Navigating array and objects data

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object that has a property link. I get it with `getLink()`. This property is actually an array so I get the 1st element `$link[0]` which in turn is an object so I get the property `getHref()`. My total code looks like this.

```
$link = $obj->getLink();
$link0 = $link[0];
$href = $link0->getHref();
```

Is there a better way to write this code, like in 1 line? something like `$obj->getLink()->get(0)->getHref()` I'm using PHP 5.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
current($obj->getLink())->getHref()
```

That's not very elegant though.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
$links = $obj->getLink();
$href  = $links[0]->getHref();
```

If `getLink` always returns an array it should be called `getLinks` (plural) and I would expect to have to iterate over the return value; working only with the first result seems weird. Alternatively, `getLink` could accept a parameter to return a specific link, e.g.:

```
$href = $obj->getLink(0)->getHref();
```

PHP doesn't support direct return value dereferencing, so either the object interface is not very well suited for the language it's written in or you're not using the object as expected.

Comment: So if I want the 3rd element, I'd do `next->next($obj->getLink())->getHref()`?

Comment: Actually I should say that this data is from an API so I can't control the structure of the data.

Comment: @sameold If you want the third result, you *have* to use an intermediate variable. As I said though, that seems like an abuse of the object. You should probably *loop over all links*. Why would you need only the third one specifically?